# How to configure Django to connect via IPv4 if IPv6 is not reachable?

Tags: django, postgresql, ipv6, ipv4

Having this database setting on Django

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'some_db',
            'USER': 'some_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'very_secure_ihjfawlkjgfhq2oi5r78q83urf',
            'HOST': 'somehost.example.com',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
```

Let's assume somehost.example.com is having both, IPv4 and IPv6 IP addresses assigned, but Postgres is not always listen on both interface. How I could configure to failover to legacy IP if "IPv6-Postgres" not proper listening?